# Modeling using data-driven approach

Tags: c#, .net

I have a task to provide solution that models some entity example animal using data-driven approach in C#?
It may the answer seems silly but can anyone tell me what modeling using data-driven approach means and provide some code sample?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A model would be a set of classes built specifically for you input data.  So each piece of input data would have an object in your class structure like a string, int, List<string>, double....

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jdweng . Can u provide some code example about this for example i have to add 3 new animals with name as properties like dog,cat,horse as an input. Is this mean i have to make 3 separate classes for this 3 ne inputs? It may the question seems silly but i m confused.If u can help this it will really mean much to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Animal
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Weight;
        public Animal(string name, int weight)
        {
            Name = name;
            Weight = weight;
        }
    }
```

and then, your main function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal Cow =  new Animal("cow", 200);
        Animal Dog =  new Animal ("dog", 15);
        Animal Cat =  new Animal ("cat", 5);
    }:
```